# O que são unions? Por que utilizá-los dentro de structs?

Tags: c, struct, union

Gostaria de entender as diferenças entre `union` e `struct`.
Percebi que ambos podem ser acessados da mesma forma:

```
u.membro
uPrt->membro

s.membro
sPrt->membro
```

Na prática já vi vários códigos utilizando `unions` dentro de `structs`. Qual a vantagem ao fazer isso? Há alguma melhoria na performance/memória?

Um exemplo de código qualquer (me corrijam se estiver errado):

```
struct pessoa {
 char[50] name;
 union {
  int idade;
  float peso;
 }
};
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A grande vantagem esta na organização da memória, e no seu reaproveitamento.

As variáveis em uma `struct` são organizadas em endereços sequenciais, de forma que cada variável que compõe a `struct` fique lado a lado na memória.

*O seu exemplo não é um bom exemplo para uma `union`, por isso, não vou utiliza-lo.*

Imagine que temos um item de supermercado. Este  `item` tem um nome, preço e dimensão. A dimensão pode ser tanto em volume (1 litro) como peso (1 Kg). Assim, poderíamos criar a seguinte `struct`:

```
struct item {
    char nome[50];
    float preco;
    float volume; // em litros.
    unsigned peso; // em gramas.
}
```

Nesta `struct item`, teríamos memória alocada do seguinte modo (estou supondo alinhamento de memória a byte, por simplicidade):

```
0-------------49-50-------53-54--------57-58-------61
      nome          preco       volume       peso
```

Note, porém, que no caso de leite, não compramos o leite por peso, e sim por volume. Logo, o campo `struct item.peso` não teria um valor válido para este item, mas sempre ocuparia memória.

O mesmo vale para o queijo: que é vendido em gramas, e não em litros.

Como reduzir então a memória utilizada? Podemos declarar dentro de uma `union` os campos `volume` e `peso`:

```
struct item {
    char nome[50];
    float preco;
    union {
        float volume;
        unsigned peso;
    }
}
```

Agora nosso layout de memória ficará:

```
0-------------49-50-------53-54-------------57
      nome          preco       volume/peso
```

Deste modo, quando acessarmos o campo `struct item.volume`, o compilador sabe que estamos tratando aquela região de memória como um `float`, e irá manipula-la corretamente. O mesmo vale para quando acessarmos `struct item.peso`, ele sabe que é um `unsigned`, e vai aplicar as regras do tipo `unsigned`.

Mas, e se fizermos:

```
struct item it;
it.peso = 2;
it.volume = 0.0f;
printf("%u", it.peso);
```

A saída não será `2`, que é o valor que colocamos na variável `peso`, e sim o valor de binário de `0.0` em IEEE 754 interpretado como um `unsigned`. Coincidentemente, este valor também é `0`, e portanto a saída será `0`.

Porque?

Lembre-se que os campos `volume` e `peso` ocupam a mesma região de memória. Logo, as atribuições escreveram no mesmo endereço.

Então, se acessarmos o valor pelo campo "errado", podemos obter resultados absurdos para nosso domínio do problema. Então como saber qual campo devemos utiizar?

Podemos adicionar uma flag nos indicando isso:

```
struct item {
    char nome[50];
    float preco;
    bool porVolume;
    union {
        float volume;
        unsigned peso;
    }
}
```

E então se quisermos imprimir o conteúdo de um item, poderíamos utilizar:

```
if ( it.porVolume ) {
    printf("%s\t%.2f\t%.3f", it.nome, it.preco, it.volume);
} else {
    printf("%s\t%.2f\t%u", it.nome, it.preco, it.peso);
}
```

E este padrão se repete para quando formos acessar os campos da `union`.

Além de utilizarmos dentro de uma `struct`, podemos utilizar uma `union` como um tipo mesmo:

```
union pesoVolume {
    float volume;
    unsigned peso;
}

union pesoVolume pv;
pv.volume = 0.0f;
```

O funcionamento é idêntico, exceto que a `union` não estará mais dentro de uma `struct`.

Na linguagem C, os campos que compõem a `union`'s podem ter tamanho diferentes, inclusive, e o compilador irá reservar memória idêntica ao tamanho da maior variável. Ou seja:

```
union u1 {
    float f1;    // 4.
    unsigned f2; // 4.
}
printf("%d", sizeof(union u1)); // 4.

union u2 {
    float f1;    // 4.
    long int f2; // 8.
    char f3[20]; // 20.
}
printf("%d", sizeof(union u2)); // 20.
```

**Quando usar?**

Hoje não faz mais muito sentido, acredito. Antigamente, memória era um recurso não abundante, e por isso justificava fazer estas economias. Hoje, o padrão de um PC é 4GB, e não é raro encontrar máquinas com 8GB ou mais.

Em alguns casos, no entanto, `union` facilita a passagem de parâmetros em uma API, podendo ser utilizada caso o programador identifique a vantagem. Isto ocorre em alguns comandos da `Win32`. Sinceramente não recomendo, pois pode ser que algumas linguagens não tenham suporte para este esta organização, causando problemas de interoperabilidade.

**Por que não utilizei seu exemplo?**

Proque provavelmente gostaríamos de manter tanto as informações da `idade` de uma pessoa, como do seu `peso`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
Achei bem detalhada e portanto dei um +1

Comment: Se a resposta tira suas dúvidas, você deve aceitá-la.

Comment: Esperava ver mais respostas para ver se havia alguma mais completa. Aceitei a sua pois como mencionei antes respondeu a questão.

Comment: Excelente resposta, @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira. Nem em livros vi uma explicação tão boa, parabéns!

Comment: É muito útil e usado em sistemas embarcados. O controlador tem registradores de memória, e cada bit ou byte tem uma função específica. Para garantir o acesso individual a cada um dos espaços de maneira única, as bibliotecas fazem o mapeamento de bits e bytes em unions.

Answer (score 8):

A diferença entre union e struct é que um struct é um "E" e armazena todos os campos enquanto um union é um "OU" e todos os campos ficam na mesma posição de memória. Se você atualizar um campo de um union todos os outros campos também serão atualizados ao mesmo tempo, para algum valor lixo.

O único caso em que você deve usar um union é quando você quiser economizar memória e tem certeza que apenas um campo é necessário de cada vez. Já para o fato de unions aparecerem dentro de structs, um problema dos unions em C é que não tem como saber qual campo está sendo usado e quais campos estão com valores "lixo". Por isso, é comum criar uma enum pra marcar isso. Por exemplo, essa struct representa tokens em uma linguagem de programação:

```
struct exp {
    enum {LIT,VAR} type;
    union {
        int lit;
        char *var;
    } value;
};
```

Um token pode ser ou um número ou um nome de variável. No campo `type` nós dizemos qual é o tipo do token e no campo value nós armazenamos o valor do token (um inteiro no caso de ser um token numérico e um ponteiro pra string caso o token seja um identificador). Usando a union, a struct `exp` tem uma representação mais compacta na memória. Só tem que tomar cuidado pra só acessar o campo `lit` depois de chacar que o campo `type` contém `LIT` e assim por diante.

Comment: Gostei do comparativo de E para structs e do comparativo de OU para unions.

Answer (score 3):

O Vinícius Gobbo e o hugomg já apresentaram explicações sobre o que é e a diferença de um struct. No entanto, gostaria de acrescentar um exemplo de uso.

```
union Valor
{
    uint32_t dword;

    struct
    {
        uint16_t word0;
        uint16_t word1;
    };

    struct
    {
        uint8_t byte0;
        uint8_t byte1;
        uint8_t byte2;
        uint8_t byte3;
    };
};
```

Que pode ser representado da seguinte forma:

[image: Representação da Memória]

Na imagem, você pode observar que word0 e word1 estão em paralelo a dword, assim como os bytes.

---

Ainda nesse exemplo, é possível operações do tipo:

```
Valor foo;
foo.dword = 305;

printf("%d", foo.word0); // Mostra a primeira word de dword.
printf("%d", foo.word1); // Mostra a segunda word de dword.

printf("%d", foo.byte0); // Mostra o primeiro byte de dword.
```

Comment: Bacana seu exemplo, mas o compilador vai ter dar alguma garantia que a memoria está alinhada corretamente não?

Comment: Kaminary, sim, tem que verificar isso sim. E também o tipo de ordenação, se é big endian ou little endian. Mas, nos que eu já utilizei isso é válido.

Comment: -1 por colocar um código perigoso e possivelmente undefined behavior.

Comment: @Kaminary: vérios compiladores implementam pragmas que permitem marcar uma struct como "packed", sem nenhum padding entre os campos. É claro, isso é uma extensão da linguagem - o padrão base só garante que os campos da struct aparecem em ordem.

Comment: @hugomg Neste caso posso assumir que o código do Lucas Nunes vai funcionar em qualquer compilar padrão ISO que não tenha esta extensão?